# Crop image from byte array

Tags: android, bitmap, arrays

My app let the user take a picture with the camera and return a byte array containing the image data (jpeg at the moment but can be modified).

If we know the width and height of the picture, is it possible to use

```
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, offset, length)
```

To decode the picture from specified offset to get a squared picture ?

The image is in high res (portrait) and I only need the squared bottom of this picture still in high res for image processing.

```
x offset = 0
y offset = height - width
width = width
height = width
```

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818415/crop-image-directly-from-byte-array) answer but I still was wondering if this was possible. I could compress image data with another format if needed

My guess was to compute the number of bytes used to store `n` rows of pixels (using known dimensions), where `n = maxRows - pictureWidth`

and then start from computed offset

Comment: see *[crop image directly from byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51347342/192373)*

Answer (score 0):

First decode to small size

```
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opt.inSampleSize = 4;  //inSampleSize == 4 returns an image that is 1/4 the width/height of the original, and 1/16 the number of pixels

BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, offset, length, opt)
```

ANd Then

```
bitMap1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitMap, width, height, true);
```

try this

Comment: but to use this function I must load my image into a bitmap, and as the file is large (3mb+) I can't load it into a bitmap without downscaling it (an the method to use would rather be `Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBmp, x, y, width, height)`

Comment: I need to have to highest resolution available for the bottom part of the image for precessing, so I can't down downsample the source image

Comment: then give opt.inSampleSize = 1; which give same resolution